# Setting Buttons to Reference Multiple xml layouts

Tags: android, eclipse, button

I have a button bar that links different xml layouts, but I can only get to one and not return to the others when I try to click on a different button. Sorry, in advance for the hassle, still bit of a novice. This is my first post here, but been referencing this site a lot. Thanks in advance.

activity_main.xml

```
   <ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"  
    android:stretchColumns="*" 
    android:background="#6B1414">
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:text="@string/Str"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:padding="18dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:background="#424242"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:text="@string/Agl"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:padding="18dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:background="#424242"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:text="@string/Int"
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="18dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:background="#424242"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:text="@string/Misc"
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:background="#424242"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:padding="18dip"/>
    </TableRow>
```

MainActivity.java

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        Button btn2 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        Button btn3 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        Button btn4 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn4);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent();
                myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                myIntent.setData(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                return;
            }
        });

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent();
                myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                myIntent.setData(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                setContentView(R.layout.agil_main);
                return;
            }
        });


        btn3.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent();
                myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                myIntent.setData(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                setContentView(R.layout.int_main);
                return;
            }
        });


        btn4.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent();
                myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                myIntent.setData(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                setContentView(R.layout.misc_main);
                return;
            }
        });

}}
```

Update. The XML looks good, thanks. I'm still stuck with the same problem I had before. I added activities for each layout, but I'm still having the same problem of not being about to cycle through the layouts. Each java file looks the same as this.

MainActivity.java (update with new .class Intents)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    Button btn2 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    Button btn3 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    Button btn4 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn4);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent();
            myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
              myIntent.setData(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            return;
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent();
            myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainAgil.class);
            myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            myIntent.setData(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            setContentView(R.layout.agil_main);
            return;
        }
    });


    btn3.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent();
            myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainInt.class);
            myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            myIntent.setData(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            setContentView(R.layout.int_main);
            return;
        }
    });


    btn4.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent();
            myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMisc.class);
            myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            myIntent.setData(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            setContentView(R.layout.misc_main);
            return;
        }
    });
```

}}

Answer (score 0):

Define your button bar in a separate XML layout. In every XML you need that bar include that button bar using [`<include/>`](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) tag. And in every activity in which XML you have included the button bar handle the onclick of the buttons separately.

Comment: Thank you sir. I added the <include/> function to all my XML layouts. It made my code much more efficient, but I'm still having the same problem, where I can get to a different XML layout when I click a button, but it gets stuck on that layout.

Comment: can you please describe your problem more clearly? what is the exact problem are you facing?

Comment: The layout comes out fine and I can click any button, for example, btn3 takes me to the correct layout, but when i try clicking btn 1, btn2 and/or btn4 it stays on the layout associated with btn3. I thought it had to do with "return" in the OnClick(View v), but I played around with it, sadly to no avail.

Comment: instead of changing the layout start new activity. you are handling all layouts in single activity. separate them in different activity